# How to start a Fragment after SearchView input

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, searchview, fragmentstatepageradapter

To be honest, I didn't know what to write as title for this question because it's a bit complex.

I have an activity, a fragment and an adapter.

The activity has a `ViewPager` which adapter is a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and depending on the selected item or position, it creates a new Instance of the fragment.

The fragment adapter loads a list of items in a `RecyclerView`. Every new instance in the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is a different string array for the `RecyclerView`.

I have set a search view in the toolbar for the activity and when there's an input in the search, it should start a function in the fragment.

These are the functions in the fragment that are listeners of the search

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        performSearch(s);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        performSearch(null);
        return false;
    }

    private void performSearch(final String query) {
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
            mTimer.purge();
        }
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mAdapter.filter(query);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 150);
    }
```

The thing is that I don't know how to get the current fragment, so I can set `fragment.onQueryTextChange(searchInput)`
and prevent it from creating a new instance of the fragment.

What I want to do, in short words, is being able to get the fragment with its already defined instance, and make it filter the array defined in the instance with text in the search input, in the same activity and page of the `ViewPager`.

I don't know if I was clear enough. But if you can help, I will be really thankful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, which fragment you are looking for.
You can get fragment from activity with `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container)` or from adapter with `mAdapter.getItem(position)`. Then for sure you can check class of fragment with `instanceof` and then call any method you want.

Comment: I have a ViewPager and its adapter is a FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: and whre is problem? you can get fragment from adapter with getItem()